# How to send immediate response on camel route after placing message on queue

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am trying to implement a pretty simple camel route whereby a request is received from a CXF endpoint and placed in a queue for later asynchronous processing. Once the message is placed on the queue I need to be able to send a response to the caller indicating that message has been received. I have been through the tutorials but cannot seem to get this working correctly. What is happening is that once the message is placed on the queue, no response is sent to the caller until the message has been processed from the queue to its intended destination.

Code below

```
    from (SOAP_ENDPOINT)
        .to(SEDA_RECEIVED)
        .transform(constant(OK))//I expect this transform to return OK to caller
        .log("OK response sent back to caller");

    from (SEDA_RECEIVED)
        .to(BEAN_CONVERT_REQUEST)
        .to("activemq:queue:events");

    from ("activemq:queue:events")
            .to(BEAN_STORE_TO_DB);
```

Comment: What route goes back to the caller in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
    to(SEDA_RECEIVED)
You can try
    inOnly(SEDA_RECEIVED)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its the event message eip
http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html

And a bit related is the wire tap eip
http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html